# SPF record has 0% success rate

Tags: spf

My domain's SPF record is passing the validations tests I have found. However, Google Postmaster is still giving me a SPF Success Rate of 0%.

Our email is done via G Suite and we conduct email marketing via MailChimp.

Here is our SPF entry in our DNS:

```
v=spf1 +a +mx include:_spf.google.com include:servers.mcsv.net ~all
```

I understand that the SPF record is related to the return path for an email but I an find any information on the exact connection.

Would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

I'm little bit late to the party, but I think [this can help](https://help.activecampaign.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002134140-Check-your-domain-reputation-with-Google-Postmaster).

> Why do I see 0% SPF success?

> ActiveCampaign manages SPF for you and 100% of your messages will pass SPF. But Google Postmaster will show 0% success for SPF because the SPF domain being checked (our mail server domain) is not the same as the domain being shown in the report (your domain). Basically, the SPF Domain and From Address domains have a 0% match, although SPF is passing.

> This is normal and has no negative impact on your deliverability. If you want to set up an SPF domain that matches your From Address you can do so by setting up a custom mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Lets first break down what your SPF record actually does.
SPF checks an incomming message for its mail header, in this header it looks for the **Mail From** header tag, which also can be known as:
**RFC.5321 from address**
**5321.from**
**Envelope From address**
**Bounce address**
**Return-Path**

It will look at anything after the @ in this tag and do a TXT lookup through DNS to find any TXT record on the domain that starts with v=spf1

Now in your record you have the following things added:
**+a**: Will resolve the CNAME of your Domain to get the IP of the host of your website.
**+mx**: Will allow mails to be send from the same address you use as your mailsystem (Mail Exchange record)
**include:_spf.google.com**: Adds all of the IP's Google use in G-suite to allow sending through their system.
**include:servers.mcsv.net**: Adds all of the IP's Mailchip uses to allow sending through their system.

**~all**: Defines what happens if the mail comes from an IP that is not resolved from any of the above, ~ is a softfail, ergo if it fails it tells the receiver to mark it as spam. **-** instead is a hardfail, telling the receiver to reject the mail if the above criteria is not met.

So far so good.
In regards to your setup, if you send an email from Mailchimp to yourself or from G-Suite to yourself it should allow it on the SPF side of things.

I would try sending emails to yourself or to someone else and see if they get caught in spam. If they do, check the mail header of the message, you can even use [MXtoolbox's very nice tool](https://mxtoolbox.com/EmailHeaders.aspx) to analyze the header (which will basically make the header easier to read).
If there is an SPF fail, it should say so right in the header.